# Extract dollar amount at multiple places in sentence in python

Tags: python, regex

I have a sentence as below where in I need to extract the dollar amounts with commas to be able to populate into a dictionary.I have tried with few options but couldn't succeed.Please guide.

```
For par\n 
$3,500 single /$7,000 group
For nonpar\n
$7,000 single  /$14,000 group
```

Expected output is :

```
"rates":{

    "single" :  "$3,500 (par) / $7,000 (nonpar)",
    "group"  :  "$7,000 (par) / $14,000 (nonpar)"
}
```

\n here is on a new line
Amount might have decimal points and commas after every 3 values as below.

I was able to write regex for amount alone,but not finding right approach to extend it to my requirement.

```
re.search(r'^\$\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*(\.\d+)?$','$1,212,500.23')
```

Edit1:
Went ahead with one more step:

```
re.findall(r'\$\d{1,3}(?:\,\d{3})*(?:\.\d{2})?', str)
```

- Could get all values in list (but need to have strategy to know which value corresponds to what?)

Edit2:

```
re.findall(r'\For par\W*(\$\d{1,3}(?:\,\d{3})*(?:\.\d{2})?\W*single)\s*\W*(\$\d{1,3}(?:\,\d{3})*(?:\.\d{2})?\W*group)', str)
```

Please help me to refine this and make it more generic.

Thanks

Comment: Are the words 'par', 'nopar', 'single' and 'group' all constants, or are they sometimes other words? How structured/consistent is this text? Eg: is there always a newline? Two dollar amounts separated by a '/' with a word following? Two entries or could there be more? Are all entries in the same format, using the same words, or do they vary in some way?

Comment: new line might be there or might not be.All the names are constant,but there can be some more content like semi colon after par or nopar,others like for par or for nonpar,at times only one of par or nonpar will be present(in such cases content after / can be excluded as it is assumed to be par)

Comment: just checked that par can be 'in' and nonpar can be 'out' at times single can be 'fellow' and group can be 'association' at times.

Comment: I brute forced and came up with **[this solution](https://regex101.com/r/fG9pZ7/2)**. Let me know if this works for your inputs. Test it at your will. Just enter text and see if substitution is correct or not.

Comment: @noob I am looking for more generalized regex which can meet my requirement.This was fine but looking for better approaches.

Comment: just help in extracting the amount for each is enough.creating the dictionary can be taken care later

Comment: Try [`^\$([\d.,]+)\s+(\S+)\s+/\$([\d.,]+)\s+(\S+)`](https://regex101.com/r/uF0uW4/2) with `re.M` flag.

Comment: You wrote: _at times only one of par or nonpar will be present(in such cases content after / can be excluded as it is assumed to be par)_. Do you really mean _it is assumed to be par_ if only _nonpar_ is present?

Comment: What I meant was that the part after / in json format can be excluded.As per our guidelines,if only one value is present,it is a par value.